# Laravel Eloquent: Load and With methods result in empty set, but accessing property without Load or With returns data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch the associated records for one-to-many relationship (groups) for an eloquent model (contact) before I send it to be serialized as JSON, but when I try to load then relationship using `$query->with('groups')` or `$contact->load('groups')` I am getting an empty set.

:(

**Contact Class**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'username';
    public $incrementing = false;

    function groups()
    {
        $relation = $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'contact_group', 'username', 'group_id')
            ->withPivot(["title as title"]);

        return $relation;
    }
}
```

Then in Tinker this returns the expected set:

`\App\Contact::where('username', 'test')->first()->groups`

But

`\App\Contact::where('username', 'test')->with('groups')->first()->groups`

and

`\App\Contact::where('username', 'test')->first()->load('groups')->groups`

return empty sets.

- Note: The primary key is a string and the foreign key appears to be a different case with the first letter capitalized `Test` and the primary key being all lowercase `test`. This then changes the questions to why am I getting results when not using `with` or `load`

Comment: You are adding with to Contact Model, the relationship must be defined there.

Comment: You are showing us `App\ContactGroup` not `App\Contact`. Can we see `App\Contact`?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code example show `App\Contact` @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
\App\Contact::with('groups')->where('username', 'test')->first();
```

That should load the related groups on the first contact with the username test.

Comment: Yeah ...it should, but it doesn't. When I use `->with('groups')` it makes `->groups` an empty array

Comment: Notice the order of the clauses, `with()` is the first clause on the model

Comment: As @Ohgodwhy metioned above, you posted the ContactGroup model, but are querying against Contact. Please post the Contact model as well.

Comment: sorry, copied the wrong code (embarrassing), I'll update the question

Comment: looking at it again, I think it may be an issue with the primary key being a string, in my test case the foreign key in the group table is capitalized for some reason. ...but that should cause it to never return results.

Comment: Why did you choose the username field as the primary key instead of an integer? username should just be a unique index.

Comment: I know. The database schema was already set before I started working on this.